# How to make change in this post title table with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is the html code-

```
<table style='min-width:60%;height:25px;'>
    <tr>
        <td><data:post.title></td>
        <td id='date-and-author' style='position: relative;bottom: -2px;white-space:nowrap;'><data:post.author><data:post.dateHeader></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This gives the following result-
**How to make html table**      by admin on 8/1/13
You can see title, admin and date all are in one line. The problem is, when device has maximum width of 480px then  **'by admin on 8/1/13'** run out of 100% window size. If i make white space= normal in id  **#date-and-author** then it is displayed like:
**by admin

on 8/1/13**
Which is not good. I want,  when device has maximum width of 480px then **'by admin on 8/1/13'** will displayed in new row. What css should i place in `@media only screen and (max-width:480px){..}` so that, id  **#date-and-author** will be displayed in new row as:
**How to make html table**
by admin on 8/1/13
I don't want to use div element. Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using tables for that? And you don't want to use a `div` for that because? A `td` is a table column, so they usually sit next to each other.

Comment: I don't want div because it is not giving desired design like table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the `td` to display as a table row (but you need to apply that to both `td`s so I gave the first `td` and ID too, or you could assign all `td`s within that table):

```
<table style='min-width:60%;height:25px;'>
<tr>
    <td id='title'><data:post.title></td>
    <td id='date-and-author' style='position: relative;bottom: -2px;white-space:nowrap;'><data:post.author><data:post.dateHeader></td>
</tr>
</table>

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    td#title, td#date-and-author { display:table-row; }
}
```